# Black Berry - How to avoid this infinite loop in this FieldChangeListener.fieldChanged

Tags: java, blackberry

I need to format the string entered by the user on a EditField.
This is my code:

```
input = new BorderedEditField(20, BasicEditField.FILTER_NUMERIC);

input.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {             
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        input.setText(pruebaTexto(input.getText()));
    }
});

public static String pruebaTexto(String r){
    return r+"0";
}
```

But it ends on a stackoverflow error caused apparently because of an infinite loop.
What is wrong with the code?

Comment: This answer is not working for my case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7571696/1293724

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent the recursion by checking whether this is an internal update.
For Blackberry, this is done by checking the value of `context`

```
input.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        if (context != FieldChangeListener.PROGRAMMATIC) {
            input.setText(pruebaTexto(input.getText()));
        }
    }
});
```

This is a non-Blackberry-specific solution that will work for any variety of listener:

```
input.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
    private boolean internalCall = false;
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        if (!internalCall) {
            internalCall = true;
            try {
                input.setText(pruebaTexto(input.getText()));
            }
            finally {
                internalCall = false;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @Lucas Checking the value of `context` against `FieldChangeListener.PROGRAMMATIC` is another approach to decide how the change event is fired.

Answer (score 1):

Check the API documentation of [`net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/FieldChangeListener.html).

When the method [`void fieldChanged(Field field, int context)`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/FieldChangeListener.html#fieldChanged%28net.rim.device.api.ui.Field,%20int%29) gets invoked you can check the parameter **`context`** against the value [`FieldChangeListener.PROGRAMMATIC`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/FieldChangeListener.html#PROGRAMMATIC).

If  **`context`** is equals to  [`FieldChangeListener.PROGRAMMATIC`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/FieldChangeListener.html#PROGRAMMATIC), then the change was made programmatically, otherwise it was an user interaction.